# Tried to add legend into line plot using ggplot2 but nothing showed up

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to add the legend to line plot by using ggplot2 but the result did not show any legend at all.

```
p = ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=data1, aes(x = dpi, y = Temp.chick1), color = "blue",size = 1) +
  geom_line(data=data2, aes(x = dpi, y = Temp.chick2),color = "red",size = 1) + 
  geom_line(data=data3, aes(x = dpi, y = Temp.chick3),color = "green",size = 1) +
  geom_line(data=dataC, aes(x = dpi, y = Temp.chickC),color = "black",size = 1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1, to = 14, by = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 40, to = 44, by = 0.1)) +
  labs(x = "Day Post Infection",
         y = "Temperature") +
 scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","green","black"))
print(p)
```

[image: The result from ggplot2]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you passed the colors as arguments. You have to map them on the color aes, i.e. put them inside `aes()` to get a legend. Also. To get the correct color mapping use a named vector inside `scale_color_manual`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
data1 <- data.frame(dpi = runif(20), Temp.chick1 = runif(20))
data2 <- data.frame(dpi = runif(20), Temp.chick2 = runif(20))
data3 <- data.frame(dpi = runif(20), Temp.chick3 = runif(20))
dataC <- data.frame(dpi = runif(20), Temp.chickC = runif(20))

p = ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=data1, aes(x = dpi, y = Temp.chick1, color = "Chicken 1"),size = 1) +
  geom_line(data=data2, aes(x = dpi, y = Temp.chick2,color = "red"),size = 1) + 
  geom_line(data=data3, aes(x = dpi, y = Temp.chick3,color = "green"),size = 1) +
  geom_line(data=dataC, aes(x = dpi, y = Temp.chickC,color = "Chicken Control"),size = 1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1, to = 14, by = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 40, to = 44, by = 0.1)) +
  labs(x = "Day Post Infection",
       y = "Temperature") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("Chicken 1" = "blue",red = "red",green = "green","Chicken Control" = "black"))
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. How can I change the name of the color? For ex, black line indicates Chicken Control.

Comment: Hi. First. You have to set the label inside the `geom_line(..., color = "Chicken Control")` and second in `scale_color_manual(values = c("Chicken Control" = "black", ...)`. Same for the other Chickens.

Comment: I did as your words but error "Unknown colour name: Chicken 1" 
```

Comment: Hm. Not sure what went wrong. Have a look at my edit. Just added some labels.